# CKeditor 5 using page styles

Tags: ckeditor5

What is the equivalent of https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/divarea in CK5? I've used this in CK4 for a previous project but I'm hoping to use CK5 for my new project. Need to inherit the page styles though for the InlineEditor. TY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CKEditor 5's classic editor](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/examples/builds/classic-editor.html), despite its name which might indicate that it's the same thing as CKEditor 4's classic editor, is not that classic.

Some of the differences were described in the ["Enhanced classic editor" section of the "What's new?" guide](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/whats-new.html#Enhanced-classic-editor). And one of the main difference is that **the new classic editor uses an inline editable element**. It makes it far lighter and causes less problems (e.g. in CKEditor 4 the iframe which holds the content needs to be resized once you type and this is super tricky).

So, in other words, the new CKEditor 5's classic editor is a bit like CKEditor 4's with the divarea plugin loaded.